# Calculating dredged material volume with sloped trapezoidal geometry using bathymetric data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, slope, volume

I have bathymetric data (as a point layer) for an area slated for dredging, where the target depth is -4m relative to Chart Datum. I have a polygon outlining the dredged area. The post-dredging configuration will result in a trapezoidal canal shape with a slope of 3:1. I've attempted to estimate the volume by creating a surface layer using TIN and using the 'Volume' plug-in. However, this method does not account for the slope of the dredged area. How can I accurately calculate the volume of dredged materials considering the 3:1 slope?

[image]